# Stop injecting more users when feeder is empty

Tags: gatling

Is there a way to use `constantUsersPerSec` or `rampUsersPerSec` injection profile on a scenario with a (json) feeder such that it doesn't throw an exception when the feeder is empty, and instead just stops injecting more users?

Comment: What is the thrown exception ?